# Defining different OnCollide()-s for different objects in component based game engine?

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics

I have a general question, which can be simply explained by this:

I have 2 objects: **bullet** and **human**.
Both of these objects have rigidbodies, and I would like to call both of their **OnCollide()** method on colliding with each other.

My question is, that **how can I implement OnCollide() differently** (and effectively) for these objects while the only difference between their game objects is their physical respresentation?

Make a **Behaviour** abstract class, which has an OnCollide method, implement this class by **BulletBehaviour** and **HumanBehaviour** class which overrides OnCollide(), then this object's OnCollide will be called in the Rigidbody's OnCollide()?

I don't think that this is a good way of solving the problem. Or is it?

Comment: Why is it you can't just give them different `OnCollide` methods?

Comment: Because they have the same Rigidbody component, just with different member values. (size, material, etc)
That's why I thought that one solution is that I define a Function Object member variable for them, so I can assign these different 'behaviours' for them, which describes its collosion.

Comment: Without knowing more details of your framework (or code examples) this is a shot in the dark. So `RigidBody` has its own `OnCollide` method. If it's a virtual function, derive `RigidBody` into `HumanRigidBody` and `BulletRigidBody` classes which override `RigidBody::OnCollide`.

Comment: This isn't very scalable. For example if I have 100 objects with different behaviours, I have to have 100 derived classes?

Comment: I would make a material class that implements the `OnCollide` method. Then similar materials will act simelarly (e.g. water will splash, rubber will bounce, e.t.c...) Then have the `RigidBody` class include a `Material` object to govern this. (e.g. limbs are made of rubber (so limb recoil), blood is made of water (so blood splash textures))